# Wireless problems (connected but no internet)

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've checked other solutions to similar sounding problems but to no avail. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS last night, experienced no problems with wireless, today, it was fine in the morning, suddenly, no internet. The wireless was still connected to my home network but

```
ping www.google.com
```

gave unknown host. If I reboot the laptop, I get an internet connection for a bit and then it dies again.

On a perhaps unrelated note, I booted up the laptop, did some local stuff, put it to sleep, woke it again later and the internet was still fine. As soon as I opened a browser to do some work it suddenly stopped working again. I just don't understand why it connects, works, and then suddenly drops. Any ideas?

Comment: See this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and post the info

Comment: Instead of editing "SOLVED" into the title you should [accept your answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/44179).

Answer (score 1):

any and all who see this. I figured out the problem by running:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

I found out my NIC: Realtek RTL8723BE, has this problem on Ubuntu, pretty much exactly as described above where the connection slows to a halt after an uncertain amount of time for no reason (It's a bug in the default drivers). I fixed it by following the guide at:

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-trusty-realtek.html

It turns out I was being a tool (I thought I had an Intel card, and hadn't checked). So for anyone else with the same symptoms that sees this here's a possible solution.